# Check if referral was received by Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, deeplink, install-referrer

I currently have Sony Xperia E6833 device and I tried to test referral using this link:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onesolutions.refferaltester&referrer=123
```

However, it only outputs:

```
 utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set)
```

Meaning  referrer parameter is not present or empty. I have Google Play version 11.2.30.

My question Is there a way to test if Google play is receving the referral link? OR why Google play is not passing the referral link.

I know it works perfectly fine on the App side and I debugged it using adb shell broadcast. Also it works fine on other android devices. So are there ways to debug on the Google play side ?

Comment: Where do you get this value from? (application, developer console, ...)

Comment: have the same issue, it stopped working on many devices (pixel, galaxies) at some point (but I'm not sure when exactly). It still work on nexus 6p though. I'm receiving `utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set) ` instead of actual referrer in INSTALL_REFERRER intent

Comment: A side note,  ```The Google Install Referrer only works when users install apps through the Google Play Store app, not when they install apps through the browser-based version of the Google Play Store ``` or going from browser to app version of google play.  https://help.tune.com/marketing-console/how-google-play-install-referrer-works/

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53481131/com-android-vending-install-referrer-somehow-parameters-are-lost-and-changed-t