# utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set) Google play referal

Tags: android, google-play, deeplink, install-referrer

I have developed an application where user can refer other users and can earn incentives. I am getting the expected UTM_SOURCE and UTM_MEDIUM values in 85% of cases but in rest of the cases i am getting utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set).

I have used latest Play Install Referrer Library from [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library) and traditional campaignReceiver in parallel.

I have spent days looking for the reason and have gone through the available answers but none of them provides the clarity. As everywhere major reason of this is mentioned as

For a deep link into Google Play where the referrer parameter is not present or empty, the referrer value provided is:

```
utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set)
```

This can not be our reason as we have created the link from [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-url-builder) and final link looks like

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abc&referrer=utm_source%3DCheck%26utm_medium%3DTest
```

Comment: Google play store checks all the mail accounts which are logged into Google play and if you are logged in with work email (enterprise domain email id)it sets the UTM property as utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set).

So try removing work email from google play store and verify.

Use Google Play URL Builder to generate campaign URL.

It's worked for me

Answer (score 1):

From @najm 's answer from this answer pointed out by @daaniaal, it's because of enterprise accounts logged into the Play Store:

> You're most likely logged into a managed account (e.g. a work email). It doesn't matter if you have your personal account active in Play Store. The Play Store consistently checks all accounts that you're signed into on that phone. If any of them are managed by an enterprise then the Play Store resets the referrer token. You can verify this by removing said account and retry sending the token.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54884659/2443123

For making it work, login with another google account(which you haven't installed application even once) and pass referrer. Referrer is bind to google account not to device.

Comment: This is incorrect, referrer is not persisted between application removals.