# Google Play Install Referrer SDK is returning "not set" when the installation comes from Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, ads, install-referrer

I'm using Google Play Install Referrer SDK to retrieve the referral content from Google Play. I'm experiencing an issue when the installation comes from an Ad placed in Google Play, in that case I'm getting "utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%set)" but I need to retrieve the source, medium and campaign. Apparently it works well with dynamic links, for example, also with organic searchs.

The question is, is it possible to retrieve 'utm_source', 'utm_medium' and 'utm_campaign' using this SDK when the installation comes from an Ad placed on Google Play? Is there any other SDK or configuration missing?

The code that I'm using is:

```
val referrerClient = InstallReferrerClient.newBuilder(mContext).build()
referrerClient.startConnection(object : InstallReferrerStateListener {
    override fun onInstallReferrerSetupFinished(responseCode: Int) {
        when (responseCode) {
            InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.OK -> {
                val installReferrer = referrerClient.installReferrer.installReferrer
                ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please check, this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/57129915/2695276